# What does the Retire button do in Homeworld (remastered)?

Tags: homeworld, homeworld-remastered-collection

I thought "retire" was "go back to the mothership and repair" but it seems it does something else because I can't find the retired ships anywhere :/

Answer (score 6):

Retiring ships commands them to be deconstructed and credit you with some RUs. It's like recycling them, so the resources can be used to create something else. This is exactly the same behavior as in the original Homeworld.

From the Homeworld one [manual](http://www.scribd.com/doc/97870330/Homeworld-Manual-PC#scribd):

> Bring up the right click menu and select the Retire command. Ships
>   given the Retire order will return to the nearest Mothership or
>   Carrier and be scrapped. A percentage of the construction cost (in
>   RUs) will be recovered. OR: Press the [I] key once you have selected
>   the ship(s) you wish to retire.

From the Homeworld 2 manual:

[image]

This is not 100% of the construction cost. I understand it's approximately 80% of the construction cost.

Comment: Do you get the same amount of RUs back or is it some percentage?

Comment: +1. Also, something useful in HW2 is to retire ships before the next mission for RUs, since the difficulty is tied directly to how many ships you have when you enter a mission. You will be sacrificing some RUs, but you can get the difficulty way down AND have a ton of RUs for construction.

Comment: @L0j1k Yep, some people call that an exploit :)

Answer (score 1):

"Retire" destroys the selected ships. It's usually used if you have obsolete ships that you no longer need, or if there's a ship limit that you're hitting.